# Is there any way to use a type-parameter within an indexer declaration?

Tags: c#, indexer, type-parameter

I don't think so, but before I give up and use a method:

```
public T this<T>[String index]
{
    get{
        //return stuff
    }
}
```

I don't have a type parameter in the class.
I just want to return a different type based on what I want to get.

for example:

```
myObject<String>["SavedString"]
```

Is there a syntax for that?
(I can't compile any of the code above, of course.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, properties can't be generic in C#. Nor can events, constructors, variables, operators or finalizers.

Basically there are generic types and generic methods, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Since properties can't be generic, the closest way you're going to get, is to do it like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public T GetValue<T>( string key ) 
    {
         // implement logic here
    }
}
```